# Identity regarding partial derivatives and polar representation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function, and $g(r, \theta) = f(r \cos \theta , r \sin \theta)$. I  need help showing that:
$$ \left( \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{ \partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{ \partial g}{\partial r} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{r^2} \left( \frac{ \partial g}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $f_x$ instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ because this requires fewer keystrokes. By the chain rule you have
\begin{equation}
g_r(r,\theta) = f_x(x,y) \cos(\theta) + f_y(x,y) \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
g_\theta(r, \theta) = f_x(x,y) r (-\sin(\theta)) + f_y(x,y) r \cos(\theta)
\end{equation}
In both equations $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. Then your identity follows from $\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 = 1$.